# template repeat on data downloaded

Tags: loops, asynchronous, dart, polymer

I want to download data from an url like this

```
var request = HttpRequest.getString(url).then(onDataLoaded)
```

And in the onDataLoaded initiate the `"template repeat=..."`

How is this possible? Currently the template repeat iterrates before my async data download is done. Or is there any other way to iterate result in dart:polymer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a observable collection like

```dart
@CustomElement('some-element')
class SomeElement extends PolymerElement {

  var data = toObservable([]);
  ...
}
```

then with

```dart
<template repeat="{{item in data}}">{{item}}</template>
```

Polymer will update the view whenever an item in `data` is added or removed.

With

```dart
  @observable
  var data = [];
```

Polymer will update the view whenever you assign another collection to `data`. You can of course combine these two

```dart
  @observable
  var data = toObservable([]);
```

`[]` can also be a map (`{}`);

Comment: I works as you describe if I assign new value to the observable. But if I use data.add("new value") it does not update view. Why?

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you. Your comment seems to miss a part. To add code in comments (as well as inline code in Q/A) enclose it in backticks.

Comment: Can you please add the complete HTML and Dart code of your component to your question.